# session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: /tmp)

Tags: codeigniter, mariadb, iis

Hola buenas tardes esto trabajando con php 7.4.9, MySQSL y iis pero cuando quiero visualizar el proyecto por medio de la URL me está mandando el siguiente error ***Fatal error: session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: /tmp) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\IntranetUCQ\system\libraries\Session\Session.php on line 143***

> Captura de pantalla del error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Configuración archivo config.php

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = '/tmp';
```

> Ruta directorio tmp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Saludos y excelente inicio de semana.

Comment: No es lo mismo '/tmp' (ruta de *nix) que 'c:\tmp' (ruta de Windows).

Comment: Hola @jachguate Como es que debería colocar la ruta?

Comment: Supongo que será precisamente "c:\tmp" pero yo no la iniciaría y dejaría esa configuración por parte del servidor. Así si mueves tu proyecto a otra máquina, funcionará sin tener que hacer cambios, siempre y cuando el servidor esté correctamente configurado.

Comment: Recomendaría dejarlo a `sys_get_temp_dir();`, pero si quieres dejarlo a tu carpeta, supongo que sería de poner `'c:/tmp'` o `'c:\tmp'`.

Comment: Sigue marcando error " session_start(): Failed to initialize storage module: user (path: c:/tmp) "

Comment: Podría ser un error de permisos, crea un script de prueba `if(is_writable('/tmp')) { echo 'Existe y se puede escribir'; } else { var_dump(file_exists('/tmp'), is_dir('/tmp')) }`  En caso de que no se pueda escribir, se revisa primero si existe y luego si es directorio, si ambas devuelven true, entonces sí es problema de permisos, de lo contrario, la ruta no es accesible para PHP, aunque también puede ser por permisos.